# Java applet in Win7/IE (only) ignores dynamic height attribute?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, windows-7, applet

I have a 10-year-old applet which has worked nicely on all browsers/platforms prior to Win7/IE. On Win7/IE, 32bit and 64bit, the applet loads but does not size correctly to fill the browser window in the vertical dimension.  Horizontal dimension is fine.  Firefox, Chrome, Safari are fine on Win7, the glitch is only with Win7/IE. No errors in the Java Console.

I'm using the object/comment/embed html syntax, as:

```
<object classid="blah" width="100%" height="100%" codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_6_0-win.cab#Version=1,6,0,00">
    <param name="code" value="lots.of.packages.then.class">
    <param name="codebase" value="/goes/here">
    <param name="archive" value="foo.jar">
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6">
    <param name="scriptable" value="false">
    <param name="MAYSCRIPT" value="true">
    <comment>
        <embed
            type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            code="lots.of.packages.then.class"
            codebase="/goes/here"
            archive="foo.jar"
            MAYSCRIPT=true
            pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_6_0-win.cab">
        <noembed>
           No support for APPLET!!
        </noembed>
        </embed>
    </comment>
</object>
```

Note the percentage syntax for the width and height attributes: `width="100%" height="100%"`.

Note that if I set the height attribute explicitly, e.g., height="1000", all's well.  Setting it with JavaScript results in the same behavior as the percentage syntax.

Has anyone seen this problem with the vertical dimension on Win7 before?  Suggestions much appreciated.

--Mark

Comment: Width & height in percentages has never been supported by the JVM.  It may work, and has been seen to, but that is merely coincidental.  Set the applets size using JS.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  Already tried this.  Results are identical to the pure HTML method posted above.  Works happily with all OS/browser versions other than Win7/IE, where the width is correct and the height is too small.  On Win7, IE seems to be ignoring the height attribute and using whatever its default is.

Comment: Added an explicit note re setting the height attribute to a non-percentage value, e.g. height="1000", to my original question.